# Datetime CURDATE() and ADDDATE() w/ minus every day

Tags: mysql, database, date, datetime

[image: How I Add the dates]

Hey Guyses!, If you already do this maybe you can help me figure this out?, As you seen in the picture, what is the best way to have the

> TABLE insertdate

decremented until the

> table adddate

reach its remaining days.

my query:

```
mysql> insert into dates values (CURDATE(), adddate(CURDATE(), interval 2 year), '2');
```

[image]

I tried this query but it won't work.

```
 mysql> select datediff(adddate, insertdate)as timelaspse from dates where dateid=2
     -> select DATE_FORMAT(timelaspse,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') from dates;
```

Comment: First of all you're missing a semicolon in your 2 SQL queries at the bottom.

Comment: @techouse oh yeah thanks ,
maybe you can tell me something more about my question?